# How to cover for loop in test class?

Tags: apex

I am writing a test class where how to cover for loop in test class

Apex class:

```
public class LeadToAccountConversionHelper {

    public static void LeadToAccountConversionHelperMethod(list<Lead> LeadList){
        try{
            set<String> emailSet = new set<String>(); 
            for(Lead lead: LeadList){
                if(lead.LeadSource != Null && lead.LeadSource.trim().length() > 0 && lead.LeadSource == 'Web')
                    emailSet.add(lead.Email);
            }

            if(emailSet.size() > 0){
                list<Account> accountList = new list<Account>();                        //used to store Account records based on lead email Ids from DB
                list<Account> newAccountList = new list<Account>();                     //used to store new account records which will get created in DB
                list<Account> familyMemberList = new list<Account>();                   //used to store family member records which will get created in DB
                list<Relationship__c> relationshipList = new list<Relationship__c>();   //used to store relationship records which will get created in DB
                list<Policy__c> newPolicyList = new list<Policy__c>();                  //used to store Policy records which will get created in DB
                map<String,Account> accountMap = new map<String,Account>();             //This will store all account records (KEY:personemail, VALUE:Account record) 
                map<String,Id> relationshipMap = new map<String,Id>();                  //This will store all relationship records (KEY:Relationship Name, VALUE:Relationship record) 

                accountList = [select Id, Relationship__c, PersonEmail, (select RecordType.Name from Policies__r) 
                                from Account where PersonEmail IN: emailSet];

                if(accountList.size() > 0){
                    for(Account acc: accountList){
                        accountMap.put(acc.PersonEmail,acc);
                    }
                }

                if(LeadList.size() != accountList.size()){
                    for(Lead lead: LeadList){
                        Relationship__c relationshipRecord = new Relationship__c();
                        if(accountMap.get(lead.Email) == Null){
                            relationshipRecord.Name = lead.FirstName != Null && lead.FirstName.trim().length() > 0?lead.FirstName+' ':'';
                            relationshipRecord.Name += lead.LastName != Null && lead.LastName.trim().length() > 0?lead.LastName:'';
                            relationshipList.add(relationshipRecord);
                        }
                    }

                    if(relationshipList.size() > 0){
                        insert relationshipList;
                        for(Relationship__c relationship: relationshipList){
                            relationshipMap.put(relationship.Name,relationship.Id);
                        }
                    }

                    for(Lead lead: LeadList){
                        if(accountMap.get(lead.Email) == Null){
                            String name = lead.FirstName != Null && lead.FirstName.trim().length() > 0?lead.FirstName+' ':'';
                            name += lead.LastName != Null && lead.LastName.trim().length() > 0?lead.LastName:'';
                            Account accountRecord = new Account(); 
                            accountRecord.RecordTypeId                  = label.Person_Account_Individual_Account_RTID;
                            accountRecord.Relationship__c               = relationshipMap.get(name)!=null?relationshipMap.get(name):null;
                            accountRecord.FirstName                     = lead.FirstName != Null && lead.FirstName.trim().length() > 0?lead.FirstName:'';
                            accountRecord.LastName                      = lead.LastName != Null && lead.LastName.trim().length() > 0?lead.LastName:'';
                            accountRecord.Date_of_Birth__c              = lead.Date_of_Birth__c!=Null?lead.Date_of_Birth__c:null;
                            accountRecord.FIN_NRIC__c                   = lead.FIN_NRIC__c != Null && lead.FIN_NRIC__c.trim().length() > 0?lead.FIN_NRIC__c:'';
                            accountRecord.Gender__c                     = lead.Gender__c != Null && lead.Gender__c.trim().length() > 0?lead.Gender__c:'';
                            accountRecord.Marital_Status__c             = lead.Marital_Status__c != Null && lead.Marital_Status__c.trim().length() > 0?lead.Marital_Status__c:'';
                            accountRecord.Nationality__c                = lead.Nationality__c != Null && lead.Nationality__c.trim().length() > 0?lead.Nationality__c:'';
                            accountRecord.how_did_you_hear_about_EI__c  = lead.How_Did_You_hear_about_EI__c != Null && lead.How_Did_You_hear_about_EI__c.trim().length() > 0?lead.How_Did_You_hear_about_EI__c:'';
                            accountRecord.AccountSource                 = lead.Lead_Source__c != Null && lead.Lead_Source__c.trim().length() > 0?lead.Lead_Source__c:'';
                            accountRecord.Walked_In_Date__c             = lead.Lead_Walk_In_Date__c != Null?lead.Lead_Walk_In_Date__c:null;
                            accountRecord.Street_Name__c                = lead.Street != Null && lead.Street.trim().length() > 0?lead.Street:'';
                            accountRecord.Postal_Code__c                = lead.PostalCode != Null && lead.PostalCode.trim().length() > 0?lead.PostalCode:'';
                            accountRecord.Country__c                    = lead.City != Null && lead.City.trim().length() > 0?lead.City:'';
                            accountRecord.Mobile__c                     = lead.Mobile__c != Null && lead.Mobile__c.trim().length() > 0?lead.Mobile__c:'';
                            accountRecord.Phone                         = lead.Phone != Null && lead.Phone.trim().length() > 0?lead.Phone:'';
                            accountRecord.PersonEmail                   = lead.Email != Null && lead.Email.trim().length() > 0?lead.Email:'';
                            accountRecord.Position__c                   = lead.Position__c != Null && lead.Position__c.trim().length() > 0?lead.Position__c:'';
                            accountRecord.Employer__c                   = lead.Employer__c != Null && lead.Employer__c.trim().length() > 0?lead.Employer__c:'';
                            accountRecord.of_Children__c                = lead.No_of_Children__c != Null && lead.No_of_Children__c.trim().length() > 0?lead.No_of_Children__c:'';
                            accountRecord.Relationship_Type__c          = 'Primary';
                            accountRecord.Number_of_Employees__c        = lead.Number_of_Employees__c; 
                            newAccountList.add(accountRecord);

                            if(lead.Spouse_Surname__c != Null && lead.Spouse_Surname__c.trim().length() > 0){
                                Account familyMemberRecord = new Account();
                                familyMemberRecord.RecordTypeId             = label.Person_Account_Individual_Account_RTID;
                                familyMemberRecord.Relationship__c          = relationshipMap.get(name)!=null?relationshipMap.get(name):null;
                                familyMemberRecord.FirstName                = lead.Spouse_Given_Name__c != Null && lead.Spouse_Given_Name__c.trim().length() > 0?lead.Spouse_Given_Name__c:'';
                                familyMemberRecord.LastName                 = lead.Spouse_Surname__c;
                                familyMemberRecord.FIN_NRIC__c              = lead.Spouse_FIN_NRIC__c != Null && lead.Spouse_FIN_NRIC__c.trim().length() > 0?lead.Spouse_FIN_NRIC__c:'';
                                familyMemberRecord.Date_of_Birth__c         = lead.Spouse_DOB__c!=Null?lead.Spouse_DOB__c:null;
                                familyMemberRecord.Employer__c              = lead.Spouse_Employer__c != Null && lead.Spouse_Employer__c.trim().length() > 0?lead.Spouse_Employer__c:'';
                                familyMemberRecord.Spouse_Occupation__c     = lead.Spouse_Occupation__c != Null && lead.Spouse_Occupation__c.trim().length() > 0?lead.Spouse_Occupation__c:'';
                                familyMemberRecord.Gender__c                = accountRecord.Gender__c=='Male'?'Female':'Male';
                                familyMemberList.add(familyMemberRecord);
                            }

                            if(lead.Child_1_Name__c != Null && lead.Child_1_Name__c.trim().length() > 0){
                                Account familyMemberRecord = new Account();
                                familyMemberRecord.RecordTypeId         = label.Person_Account_Individual_Account_RTID;
                                familyMemberRecord.Relationship__c      = relationshipMap.get(name)!=null?relationshipMap.get(name):null;
                                familyMemberRecord.LastName             = lead.Child_1_Name__c;
                                familyMemberRecord.Date_of_Birth__c     = lead.Child_1_DOB__c != Null?lead.Child_1_DOB__c:null;
                                familyMemberList.add(familyMemberRecord);
                            }

                            if(lead.Child_2_Name__c != Null && lead.Child_2_Name__c.trim().length() > 0){
                                Account familyMemberRecord = new Account();
                                familyMemberRecord.RecordTypeId         = label.Person_Account_Individual_Account_RTID;
                                familyMemberRecord.Relationship__c      = relationshipMap.get(name)!=null?relationshipMap.get(name):null;
                                familyMemberRecord.LastName             = lead.Child_2_Name__c;
                                familyMemberRecord.Date_of_Birth__c     = lead.Child_2_DOB__c != Null?lead.Child_2_DOB__c:null;
                                familyMemberList.add(familyMemberRecord);
                            }

                            if(lead.Child_3_Name__c != Null && lead.Child_3_Name__c.trim().length() > 0){
                                Account familyMemberRecord = new Account();
                                familyMemberRecord.RecordTypeId         = label.Person_Account_Individual_Account_RTID;
                                familyMemberRecord.Relationship__c      = relationshipMap.get(name)!=null?relationshipMap.get(name):null;
                                familyMemberRecord.LastName             = lead.Child_3_Name__c;
                                familyMemberRecord.Date_of_Birth__c     = lead.Child_3_DOB__c != Null?lead.Child_3_DOB__c:null;
                                familyMemberList.add(familyMemberRecord);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if(familyMemberList.size() > 0)
                        insert familyMemberList;

                    if(newAccountList.size() > 0){
                        insert newAccountList;
                        for(Account acc: newAccountList){
                            accountMap.put(acc.PersonEmail,acc);
                        }
                    }
                }

                for(Lead lead: LeadList){
                    if(lead.LeadType__c != Null && lead.LeadType__c.trim().length() > 0 && accountMap.get(lead.Email) != Null){
                        Policy__c policyRecord                  = new Policy__c();
                        policyRecord.Account__c                 = accountMap.get(lead.Email).Id;
                        policyRecord.Type_of_Plan_Required__c   = lead.Type_of_Plan_Required__c!=Null && lead.Type_of_Plan_Required__c.trim().length() > 0?lead.Type_of_Plan_Required__c:'';

                        if(lead.LeadType__c == 'Medical'){
                            policyRecord.RecordTypeId       = label.Policy_Medical_Insurance_RTID;
                            policyRecord.Maternity_Cover__c = lead.Maternity_Cover__c!=Null && lead.Maternity_Cover__c.trim().length() > 0?lead.Maternity_Cover__c:'';
                            policyRecord.Employer_Benefits__c = lead.Employee_Benefits__c !=Null && lead.Employee_Benefits__c.trim().length() >0?lead.Employee_Benefits__c:'';
                            policyRecord.Cover_for_H_S__c = lead.Cover_for_H_S__c != Null && lead.Cover_for_H_S__c.trim().length()>0?lead.Cover_for_H_S__c:'';
                            policyRecord.Cover_for_Outpatient__c = lead.Cover_for_Outpatient__c != Null && lead.Cover_for_Outpatient__c.trim().length()>0?lead.Cover_for_Outpatient__c:'';
                            policyRecord.Client_Details__c = lead.Client_Details__c != Null && lead.Client_Details__c.trim().length()>0?lead.Client_Details__c:'';                      
                        }else if(lead.LeadType__c == 'Home'){
                            policyRecord.RecordTypeId = label.Policy_Home_Insurance_RTID;
                            policyRecord.Category__c = lead.Category__c != Null && lead.Category__c.trim().length()>0 ?lead.Category__c:'';
                            policyRecord.Item_Description__c = lead.Item_Description__c != Null && lead.Item_Description__c.trim().length()>0 ?lead.Item_Description__c:'';
                            policyRecord.Value__c = lead.Value__c;
                            policyRecord.General_Household_Contents__c = lead.General_Household_Contents__c;
                            policyRecord.Valuable_Items_Additional_Info__c = lead.Valuable_Items_Additional_Info__c;
                            policyRecord.Level_of_Personal_Liability__c = lead.Level_of_Personal_Liability__c != Null && lead.Level_of_Personal_Liability__c.trim().length()>0 ? lead.Level_of_Personal_Liability__c:'';
                            policyRecord.Declined_coverage_in_last_3_years__c = lead.Declined_coverage_in_last_3_years__c != Null && lead.Declined_coverage_in_last_3_years__c.trim().length() >0? lead.Declined_coverage_in_last_3_years__c:'';
                        }else if(lead.LeadType__c == 'Motor'){
                            policyRecord.RecordTypeId = label.Policy_Motor_Insurance_RTID;
                            policyRecord.Reg__c  = lead.Reg__c;
                            policyRecord.No_of_years_Driving__c = lead.No_of_years_Driving__c;
                            policyRecord.Singapore_NCD__c = lead.Singapore_NCD__c != Null && lead.Singapore_NCD__c.trim().length()>0? lead.Singapore_NCD__c:'';
                            policyRecord.Date_of_Loss__c = lead.Date_of_Loss__c;
                            policyRecord.Loss_Description__c = lead.Loss_Description__c != Null && lead.Loss_Description__c.trim().length() >0 ? lead.Loss_Description__c:'';
                            policyRecord.Any_claims_in_last_3_years__c = lead.Any_claims_in_last_3_years__c != Null && lead.Any_claims_in_last_3_years__c.trim().length() >0 ? lead.Any_claims_in_last_3_years__c:'';
                            //policyRecord.Nature_of_Claim__c = lead.Nature_of_Claim__c != Null && lead.Nature_of_Claim__c.trim().length()>0 ? lead.Nature_of_Claim__c:'';
                        }else if(lead.LeadType__c == 'Travel'){
                            policyRecord.RecordTypeId = label.Policy_Travel_Insurance_RTID;
                            policyRecord.Coverage_Type__c = lead.Coverage_Type__c != Null && lead.Coverage_Type__c.trim().length() >0? lead.Coverage_Type__c:'';
                            policyRecord.Travel_Plan__c = lead.Travel_Plan__c;
                            //policyRecord.Start_Date__c = lead.Start_Date__c;
                            policyRecord.Expiry_Date__c = lead.Expiry_Date__c;
                            policyRecord.Sports_Cover_Required__c = lead.Sports_Cover_Required__c;
                            policyRecord.If_Yes_State_Sport_s__c = lead.If_Yes_State_Sports_S__c;
                            policyRecord.Travel_Addtional_Comments__c = lead.Travel_Additional_Comments__c;
                        }else if(lead.LeadType__c == 'Life'){
                            policyRecord.RecordTypeId = label.Policy_Life_Insurance_RTID;
                            policyRecord.Smoker__c = lead.Smoker__c != null && lead.Smoker__c.trim().length()>0 ? lead.Smoker__c:'';
                            //policyRecord.Term_Life_Cover_c__c= lead.Term_Life_Cover__c != null && lead.Term_Life_Cover__c.trim().length() >0?lead.Term_Life_Cover__c:'';  
                            //policyRecord.Whole_Life_Cover__c =lead.Whole_Life_Cover__c != null && lead.Whole_Life_Cover__c.trim().length() >0?lead.Whole_Life_Cover__c:'';
                            //policyRecord.TPD_Cover__c = lead.TPD_Cover__c !=null && lead.TPD_Cover__c.trim().length()>0 ?lead.TPD_Cover__c:'';
                        }
                        else if(lead.LeadType__c == 'Commercial')
                            policyRecord.RecordTypeId = label.Policy_Commercial_Insurance_RTID;
                            policyRecord.Business_Additional_Comments__c = lead.Business_Additional_Comments__c;
                        newPolicyList.add(policyRecord);
                    }
                }

                if(newPolicyList.size() > 0)
                    insert newPolicyList;
            }   
        }catch(Exception e){
            system.debug('Exception == '+e.getMessage());
            system.debug('Line Number == '+e.getLineNumber());
        }
    }

}
```

Test class:

```
@isTest
private class LeadToAccountConversionTest {

    static testMethod void myUnitTest() {

        Account acc = new Account();
    acc.RecordTypeId = label.Person_Account_Individual_Account_RTID;
    acc.firstName = 'Test';
    acc.lastName = 'Account';
    acc.PersonEmail = 'test@test.com';
    acc.Advisor__c = 'Admin';
    acc.Type = 'Client';
    acc.how_did_you_hear_about_EI__c = 'Partner';
    acc.Converted_Date_WF__c = system.today();
    insert acc;


    list<Lead> leadList = new list<Lead>();
    for(Integer i=0;i<6;i++){
      Lead lead = new Lead();
      lead.FirstName = 'Test';
      lead.LastName = 'Lead Conversion';
      lead.Date_of_Birth__c = system.today();
      lead.FIN_NRIC__c = 'TESTLC';
      lead.Gender__c = 'Male';
      lead.Marital_Status__c = 'Married';
      lead.Nationality__c = 'Singapore';
      lead.How_Did_You_hear_about_EI__c = 'Adds';
      lead.Lead_Source__c = 'Web';
      lead.Lead_Walk_In_Date__c = system.today();
      lead.Street = 'Test Street';
      lead.PostalCode = '112233';
      lead.City = 'SG';
      lead.Mobile__c = '99876543';
      lead.Phone = '98765432';
      lead.Email = i<2?'test@test.com':'test123@test.com';
      lead.Position__c = 'Test POS';
      lead.Employer__c = 'Test EMP';
      lead.No_of_Children__c = '2';
      lead.Spouse_Given_Name__c = 'Test';
      lead.Spouse_Surname__c = 'Lead Conversion Spouse';
      lead.Spouse_FIN_NRIC__c = 'TESTLCS';
      lead.Spouse_DOB__c = system.today();
      lead.Spouse_Employer__c = 'N/A';
      lead.Spouse_Occupation__c = 'N/A';
      lead.Child_1_Name__c = 'Child 1';
      lead.Child_1_DOB__c = system.today();
      lead.Child_2_Name__c = 'Child 2';
      lead.Child_2_DOB__c = system.today();
      lead.Child_3_Name__c = 'Child 3';
      lead.Child_3_DOB__c = system.today();
      lead.Type_of_Plan_Required__c = 'Insurer';

      if(i==0){
        lead.LeadType__c = 'Medical';
        lead.Employer_Benefits__c ='Yes';
        lead.Cover_for_H_S__c = 'test';
        lead.Cover_for_Outpatient__c = 'Yes';
        lead.Client_Details__c ='yes';
        lead.Maternity_Cover__c = 'Yes';
      }else if(i==1)
        lead.LeadType__c = 'Home';
      else if(i==2)
        lead.LeadType__c = 'Motor';
      else if(i==3)
        lead.LeadType__c = 'Travel';
      else if(i==4)
        lead.LeadType__c = 'Life';
      else if(i==5)
        lead.LeadType__c = 'Commercial';

      leadList.add(lead);
    }
        insert leadList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Specifically what coverage is missing?

Comment: Given that the testmethod only inserts Account and Lead, I presume there is some trigger on Lead that does automatic lead conversion? if yes, your testmethod needs system.asserts to verify that the code does what it is supposed to do. Simple code coverage testmethods is not best practice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure which part of code need coverage - (which for loop) - still here you go from what I understood -

If I look at your helper class code I can see one thing common in each and every for loop there that is **LeadList** list of Lead records.
Let talk about this for loop -

```
for(Lead lead: LeadList){
                if(lead.LeadSource != Null && lead.LeadSource.trim().length() > 0 && lead.LeadSource == 'Web')
                    emailSet.add(lead.Email);
            }
```

then make sure that your **LeadList** has at least one record in it. Do debug before for loop and see whether it contains some records in it, by simply writing

`System.Debug('----My LeadList---'+LeadList);`

if not then it has to have records in it to cover that for loop.